# import MongoInternals in Meteor+React

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-react

I need to connect external MongoDb database

my code
/imports/api/Connection.js

```
import { MongoInternals } from 'meteor/mongo'; // i am probably wrong here!!
import CONST from './Constants.js';

let Connection = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(CONST.mongo);
export {Connection};
```

/imports/api/ABC.js

```
import {Connection} from './Connection.js';
let ABC = new Mongo.Collection('abc', {
    _driver: Connection
});
export {
    ABC
};
```

It return MongoInternals not defined i didn't find any where from where to import MongoInternals.

Please help me to find solution

Thanks

Comment: Where does your code run? MongoInternals is only available on server